# Generate requests to my webapp from different countries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, geolocation

I am testing the I18n and L10n of my webapp and I'am doing some handling with http://www.rubygeocoder.com/ to retrieve the country that has originated the request and then set a proper locale. I'am using Rails 3.2 in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit of a hack, but there are a number of server monitoring services having nodes located around the globe.  Pingability.com offers a free trial, as does Alertra.com and both provide reasonably sophisticated tools for doing non-trivial requests (e.g. POST) if needed.  I am sure there are scores of other similar services, but those are ones I have used.